# Redirect issues with Spring Boot on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: nginx, amazon-web-services, elastic-beanstalk, springboot

I've just put a new Spring Boot application on aws via elastic beanstalk. The app has its own static website that it hosts. When I run it locally I can go to `localhost:5000` and it redirects me to `localhost:5000/index.html` which then rewrites the url for me with React router to display my login page at `localhost:5000/login`.

In AWS, though, accessing the root url `my-app.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com` returns a 403 access denied, which is presumably due to my Spring Security config, except I don't get why it isn't redirecting to `my-app.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/index.html` like I would expect.

What's the easiest way to fix this? This is just for a demo, so I'm more interested in easiest than the best long term solution.

Comment: I'd encourage looking for the right/best long term answer since the question will be archived and searchable for posterity.  An answer that also includes simplified versions for prototyping would be a good addition for completeness.  A hacky answer on its own, however, may become the de facto standard for the future and lead others astray.

Comment: @MatthewWetmore Yeah, sure. I'm happy to accept an answer that's better as a long term solution. But first I'm just looking for any answer or help at all!